# Adding 1 year date and week days in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update, dayofweek

I have database table as Calendar with LoginDate And LoginDay as columns. I want to Add date and day of the week for next 1 year. I know how to do it for one column but I have to do that for both the columns.

```
UPDATE timsheetdb.calendar
SET LoginDate = DATE_ADD('2016-02-29', INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
```

Comment: what is datatype of `LoginDay`?

Comment: @bluto LoginDate as 'Date' and LoginDay as 'Varchar'

Comment: so LoginDay is like Monday Tuesday Wednesday?

Comment: @tofutim  yes you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the `LoginDay` shouldn't even be a column in the table. Since it's just a specific format for `LoginDate`, you can drop it, and generate it on the fly, using the [`dayname`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function, e.g., as part of a view:

```
CREATE VIEW calendar_view AS
SELECT *, DAYNAME(LoginDate) AS LoginDay
FROM   calendar
```

If this is not an option, you could use the same function in your `update` statement:

```
UPDATE timsheetdb.calendar 
SET    LoginDate = DATE_ADD('2016-02-29', INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
       LoginDay = DAYNAME(LoginDate = DATE_ADD('2016-02-29', INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```